# Summing terms without for loop in R

Tags: r, loops

Given two vectors x and y:

```
x <- c(2.9, 6.7, 8.0, 3.1, 2.0, 4.1, 2.2, 8.9, 8.1, 7.9, 5.7, 1.6, 6.6, 3.0, 6.3)
y <- c(5.8 13.4 16.0  6.2  4.0  8.2  4.4 17.8 16.2 15.8 11.4  3.2 13.2  6.0 12.6)
mean_x = mean(x)
mean_y = mean(y)
```

I want to calculate the OLS estimate for beta_1 with the formula:

```
beta_1 = sum_i (x_i - mean(x)) (y_i - mean (y))/ sum_i (x_i - mean(x))^2.
```

I am aware that I could loop with a for loop over the elements of x and y - is there, however, a way to do this in R avoiding loops?

Edit: I do *not* want to use lm. My question is specifically how summation over these terms can be done without a for loop - the OLS is just an example.

Comment: In R you would just fit a linear model and extract the estimate: `coef(lm(y~x))[2]`

Comment: That's not the question. I don't want to use lm, but use the analytical formula.

Comment: Why not? Is this for some sort of homework assignment? Is there a good reason to avoid the built in functions for something like this?

Comment: Try direct arithmetic on the vectors: `beta_1 = sum(x - mean(x)) * (y - mean(y))) / sum(x - mean(x))^2.`

Comment: Thanks @Parfait that's what I was looking for  - but why is the answer so different from Tur's answer below?

Comment: You have closing parentheses missing, so not sure what you mean

Comment: @pugl if you could give an example with a small pair if vectors with the answer calculated it would be a little easier for us to check if solutions work

Comment: You have 7 opening and 5 closing brackets but OK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be how to do it with matrix algebra, assuming x is a matrix with a column of 1s and a column of values that correspond to the `x_1` in the original equation.  It has the advantage of being generalizable and also giving you b_0.

```
x_0 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
x_1 <- c(3,4,5,6,7)
x <- matrix(c(x_0, x_1), ncol =2 )
y <- c(4, 5, 4, 7, 9)
```

```
MASS::ginv(t(x) %*% x)%*% t(x) %*% y
```

This would be how to do it with  non linear algebra, but you need to get b_0 separately.

```
b_1 = sum((x_1- mean(x_1))*(y- mean (y)))/ sum ((x_1 - mean(x_1))^2)
```

But if you really want to do it that way you could use one of the "calculating  formulas" that will involve less nesting.